# Plotly: How to make stacked bar chart from single trace?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Is it possible to have two stacked bar charts side by side each of them coming from a single column?

Here's my df:

```
Field       Issue

Police      Budget cuts
Research    Budget cuts
Police      Time consuming
Banking     Lack of support
Healthcare  Lack of support
Research    Bureaucracy
Healthcare  Bureaucracy
Banking     Budget cuts
```

I want a stacked bar chart of Field next to a stacked bar chart of issues by field.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For an example on how to make a stacked bar chart with the specific dataset provided, take a look at the suggestion in [Plotly-Dash: Want two stacked bar charts side by side from single df column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55238122/plotly-dash-want-two-stacked-bar-charts-side-by-side-from-single-df-column/55240155#55240155). The following answer addresses how you **can not** make a stacked bar chart with a ***single trace***. To show you why, I'll start with what may seem like redundant details. But hopefully everything will be clear in the end.

---

In plotly terms, `trace` is used to describe a `graph object` such as `Scatter` or `Bar` like in the snippet below.

**Snippet 1.1:**

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=['CategoryA', 'CategoryB', 'CategoryC'],
                       y=[20, 14, 23]))
fig.update_layout(template = 'plotly_dark').show()
```

If you look at the snippet above, you'll see that **that** is a bar chart with a single trace in the form of `go.Bar(x=['CategoryA',...`.

**Plot 1.1:**

[image]

Now, how can we add something to make it a `stacked chart`? If you start out by adding an element to `x` like `'CategoryD'`, then ***nothing*** happens. And that's a bit interesting since you'd might expect an error message instead.

**Plot 1.2:** Added x value

[image]

**Snippet 1.2**

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=['CategoryA', 'CategoryB', 'CategoryC', 'CategoryD'],
                       y=[20, 14, 23]))
fig.update_layout(template = 'plotly_dark').show()
```

But nothing happens before `CategoryD` has a corresponding y value like `15`:

**Plot 1.3:** Added x and y value

Conclusion so far: Adding values to `x` and `y` will add another category on the x-axis and a value on the y-axis. As you can see, nothing is getting `stacked` here quite yet:

[image]

**Snippet 1.3:**

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=['CategoryA', 'CategoryB', 'CategoryC', 'CategoryD'],
                       y=[20, 14, 23, 15]))
fig.update_layout(template = 'plotly_dark').show()
```

But what if you add a layout term with `barmode='stack'`?

---

**Snippet 2:**

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=['CategoryA', 'CategoryB', 'CategoryC', 'CategoryD'],
                       y=[20, 14, 23, 15]))

fig.update_layout(barmode='stack',
                  title = 'Stacked bar chart',
                  template = 'plotly_dark').show()
```

**Plot 2:** barmode='stack'

[image]

I can understand anyone hoping that this would stack all data within a single trace, but plotly just isn't built that way. To get what you need, you'll have to add another trace using `fig.add_trace(go.Bar())` or `simply fig.add_bar()`.

**Snippet 3:**

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=['CategoryA', 'CategoryB', 'CategoryC', 'CategoryD'],
                       y=[20, 14, 23, 15]))
fig.add_bar(x=['CategoryA', 'CategoryB', 'CategoryC', 'CategoryD'],
            y=[5, 14, 4, 20])
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack',
                  title = 'Stacked bar chart!',
                  template = 'plotly_dark').show()
```

**Plot 3:** Add trace

[image]

Notice that neither of the `go.Bar()` objects have had any name assigned to them, and that plotly by default names them `trace 0` and `trace 1`. So I guess it's more correct to say that a trace contains or 'shows' a plotly graph object rather than calling them the same thing. If you'd like to specify other names, you can do so with, for example, `name = 'segment 1'` like this:

**Snippet 4:**

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=['CategoryA', 'CategoryB', 'CategoryC', 'CategoryD'],
                       y=[20, 14, 23, 15],
                       name = 'segment 1'))
fig.add_bar(x=['CategoryA', 'CategoryB', 'CategoryC', 'CategoryD'],
            y=[5, 14, 4, 20],
            name = 'segment 2')
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack',
                  title = 'Stacked bar chart!',
                  template = 'plotly_dark').show()
```

**Plot 4:** Add named traces

[image]

If you'd like to 'unstack' your bars, just change barmode to `'group'` like this:

```
fig.update_layout(barmode='group'),
```

**Plot 5:**

[image]